# Python KeyError: 'TOT' - What is it? Why am I getting it?

Tags: python, keyerror

I scoured the internet, but couldn't even find a mention of what this particular keyerror represents. This code

```
Player_p_dict = {}      
for player in Players:
    pp = float(Player_dict[player][0])/Team_dict[Player_dict[player][1]]
    Player_p_dict[player] = pp

print Player_p_dict
```

returns the error message

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):   File "FantasyNHL.py", line 818,
in <module>
     pp = float(Player_dict[player][0])/Team_dict[Player_dict[player][1]]
 KeyError: 'TOT'
```

Where Player_dict is a dictionary with list entries, and Team_dict is another dictionary(surprising, I know).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`KeyError` happens e.g. if you try to access a non-existing key in a dictionary,

`KeyError: 'TOT'` means the key it was looking for is `'TOT'`

I see you assigned `Player_p_dict[player]` but you're reading the key `player` on `Player_dict` that could be it

Comment: Currently feeling like an idiot. I'm used to KeyErrors giving me numbers, and the string was unexpeted. I copied over a lists of players and the teams they were on, and in the hundreds of names didn't realize a few of the players were free agents. Since I was only expecting team acronym keys, I didnt recognize the free agent acronym for what it was. Thanks a bunch

Answer (score 0):

`KeyError` means you're referencing a dictionary key that does not exist. The error is in one of these two calls:

```
Player_dict[player]
# or
Team_dict[Player_dict[player][1]]
```